# Angular 5 wont update to version 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**EDIT**

So after looking into it thoroughly I also found this little message

> No compatible version found: @angular/router@6.0.0
>   Valid install targets:

```
6.0.0-rc.4, 6.0.0-rc.3, 6.0.0-rc.2, 6.0.0-rc.1, 6.0.0-rc.0, 6.0.0-beta.8, 
6.0.0-beta.7, 6.0.0-beta.6, 6.0.0-beta.5, 6.0.0-beta.4, 6.0.0-beta.3, 6.0.0-    
beta.2, 6.0.0-beta.1, 6.0.0-beta.0, 5.2.9, 5.2.8, 5.2.7, 5.2.6, 5.2.5, 5.2.4,  
5.2.3, 5.2.2, 5.2.1, 5.2.0, 5.2.0-rc.0, 5.2.0-beta.1, 5.2.0-beta.0, 5.1.3,     
5.1.2, 5.1.1, 5.1.0, 5.1.0-rc.1, 5.1.0-rc.0, 5.1.0-beta.2, 5.1.0-beta.1, 5.1.0-  
beta.0, 5.0.5, 5.0.4, 5.0.3, 5.0.2, 5.0.1, 5.0.0, 5.0.0-rc.9, 5.0.0-rc.8, 5.0.0- 
rc.7, 5.0.0-rc.6, 5.0.0-rc.5, 5.0.0-rc.4, 5.0.0-rc.3, 5.0.0-rc.2, 5.0.0-rc.1,  
5.0.0-rc.0, 5.0.0-beta.7, 5.0.0-beta.6, 5.0.0-beta.5, 5.0.0-beta.4, 5.0.0-  
beta.3, 5.0.0-beta.2, 5.0.0-beta.1, 5.0.0-beta.0, 4.4.6, 4.4.5, 4.4.4, 4.4.3,     
4.4.2, 4.4.1, 4.4.0-RC.0, 4.3.6, 4.3.5, 4.3.4, 4.3.3, 4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.3.0,     
4.3.0-rc.0, 4.3.0-beta.1, 4.3.0-beta.0, 4.2.6, 4.2.5, 4.2.4, 4.2.3, 4.2.2,    
4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.2.0-rc.2, 4.2.0-rc.1, 4.2.0-rc.0, 4.2.0-beta.1, 4.2.0-beta.0,  
4.1.3, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.1.0-rc.0, 4.1.0-beta.1, 4.1.0-beta.0, 4.0.3,   
4.0.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.0, 4.0.0-rc.6, 4.0.0-rc.5, 4.0.0-rc.4, 4.0.0-rc.3, 4.0.0-rc.2,    
4.0.0-rc.1, 4.0.0-rc.0, 4.0.0-beta.8, 4.0.0-beta.7, 4.0.0-beta.6, 4.0.0-beta.5,    
4.0.0-beta.4, 4.0.0-beta.3, 4.0.0-beta.2, 4.0.0-beta.1, 4.0.0-beta.0, 3.4.10,     
3.4.9, 3.4.8, 3.4.7, 3.4.6, 3.4.5, 3.4.4, 3.4.3, 3.4.2, 3.4.1, 3.4.0, 3.3.1,     
3.3.0, 3.3.0-rc.0, 3.3.0-beta.1, 3.3.0-beta.0, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1,     
3.2.0, 3.2.0-rc.0, 3.2.0-beta.1, 3.2.0-beta.0, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.1.0-rc.0,     
3.1.0-beta.0, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0-rc.3, 3.0.0-rc.2, 3.0.0-rc.1, 3.0.0-    
beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.1, 3.0.0-alpha.8, 3.0.0-alpha.7, 3.0.0-alpha.6, 3.0.0-        
alpha.5, 3.0.0-alpha.4, 3.0.0-alpha.3, 3.0.0-alpha.2, 3.0.0-alpha.1, 3.0.0-    
alpha.0, 2.0.0-rc.2, 2.0.0-rc.1, 2.0.0-rc.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.0, 0.0.1, 0.0.0-    
ROUTERPLACEHOLDER, 0.0.0-7, 0.0.0-6, 0.0.0-5, 0.0.0-4, 0.0.0-3, 0.0.0-2, 0.0.0-1, 0.0.0-0
```

### I suppose the install command is wrong or something along those lines

I'm currently using Angular 5.2 and want to update to Angular 6.

I followed [Angulars update guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) from 5.2 to 6 using a basic app complexity.
It provides me this command

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^6.0.0' @angular/common@'^6.0.0' 
@angular/compiler@'^6.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^6.0.0' @angular/core@'^6.0.0'  
@angular/forms@'^6.0.0' @angular/http@'^6.0.0' @angular/platform-
browser@'^6.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^6.0.0' @angular/platform-
server@'^6.0.0' @angular/router@'^6.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

but this doesnt seem to work.

**Error message**

> This is most likely not a problem with npm itself. In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't exist.

This is how my package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "tree-view",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primeng": "^5.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Version 6.0.0 of angular is not available yet. The latest release is 6.0.0-rc.4.

Comment: OHHH, so thats the case...I know that they are about to release it and thought it is available since the update guide provides you the specific command. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest angular version currently as mentioned in the comments by R.Richard is [6.0.0-rc4](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

You are getting the issue because the stable version is not available currently.

The tentative release schedule is present [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_SCHEDULE.md).